# Carriage Return/Line Feed within Javascript New Window URL

Tags: javascript

I have a requirement to open a new (_blank) window using the Javascript Window.Open function. It appears that the URL encoded carriage-return/line feed (%0A) doesn't work. Does anyone know of a fix for this? For example, I have the below URL, which should open a new window, and show a text box with the Ids 12, 34, 56, 78 and 90. When I click the link, nothing happens. If I remove the %0A, it works.

```
javascript:void(window.open('http://www.website.com/request.jsp?Ids=12%0A34%0A56%0A78%0A90','_blank'));
```

Comment: Why not just comma-separate them instead of using encoded whitespace?

Comment: I don't have that option, otherwise I would. The application is really made to take ONE ID at a time, however there is functionality that allows multiple IDs to be entered, however each needs to be on a new line.

Comment: Does it work if you type in `http://www.website.com/request.jsp?Ids=12%0A34%0A56%0A78%0A90` manually in browser's location bar?

Comment: I guess you could try `\r\n` directly instead of the encoded values, but this seems like a server-side encoding issue. Have you been able to send whitespace through the GET string successfully?

Comment: JSFiddle seems to suggest that might work: http://i.imgur.com/s0NRfpz.png All depends on how the server-side code handles it, though.

Comment: @LucioPaiva - yes, I can enter the URL into my address bar, and it works.

Comment: @JaredFarrish - If I put \r\n in the URL location, it gets encoded, and then placed into the page literally, as "\r\n". I don't see this as an issue with server-side code. It seems to be a limitation of JavaScript, as I can't even get the link the open...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you approach it by using `encodeURIComponent` on your query string and using the javascript representation of the newline character `\n`. Like this:

```
javascript:void(window.open('http://www.website.com/request.jsp?Ids='+encodeURIComponent('12\n34\n56\n78\n90'),'_blank'));
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3qwLdozh/1/)

Comment: Thanks! That works!
Now I need to get it to work in SSRS, which is going to be a pain...
-- Edit - managed to get it working in SSRS, had to play around with quote marks a bit :)

Comment: The trick is to use encodeURIComponent inside window.open() if you call it outside and add the result to the function call it will not work